gtsummary with "top 10"
Is there a way to only have the 10 most frequent entries for a gtsummary tbl_summary with categorical data?
I'm currently using the following code
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

table<- fct_count(df$name, sort = T, prop = T)%>%
  slice_head(n = 10)
table$p<- round(table$p, digits = 3)
table$p<- table$p * 100
table %<>% rename(Organism = f,`%` = p)
table

Which produces a beautiful table in the console:

But ideally I would have it in a gtsummary table (because that's what the rest of my report is using).
I can make the tbl_summary no problems, I just can't figure out how to limit to only the 10 most common organisms, and I haven't seen this asked/answered anywhere.
example dataset
library(AMR)
df<- data.table::as.data.table(example_isolates)
df$name<- mo_name(df$mo)


You could determine the top 10 beforehand and then convert the name to a factor with "Other" as the last level.
df <- data.table::as.data.table(example_isolates)
df$name<- mo_name(df$mo)
df

top10 <- names(rev(tail(sort(table(df$name)), 10)))

df %>%
  mutate(name=factor(case_when(name %in% top10~name,
                        .default="(Other)"),
                     levels=c(top10, "(Other)"))) %>%
  tbl_summary(include=name)



As tbl_summary does not provide such a functionality out of the box, you could first lump all levels which are not in the top 10 into a special category and then remove this very entry via remove_row_type:
remove_me <- "(Remove)"
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(name2 = fct_lump($name, 10, other_level = remove_me))

tbl_summary(df, include = name2, 
            sort = all_categorical(FALSE) ~ "frequency") %>%
  remove_row_type(name2, type = "level", level_value = remove_me)




Personally, I would maybe even include the lumped factor in the table (labeled "(Other)") at the end.
other_category <- "(Other)"
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(name3 = fct_lump(name, 10, other_level = other_category) %>%
                    fct_infreq() %>%
                    fct_relevel(other_category, after = Inf))

tbl_summary(df, include = name3)



The percentages are not based on the original data.

Good point, I remove solution 1.

df0$name[!df0$name %in% names(head(sort(table(df0$name), TRUE), 10))] = "Other"
library(gtsummary)
tbl_summary(data.frame(name = df0$name), 
            sort = all_categorical() ~ "frequency") #optional

giving

